# (Laravel) how to sum a data from table and save the result in another one?

Tags: laravel, api

i'm using Laravel to  build a quizzes database ( API) and i have the following table :

```
(id , student , question , category , points )
```

each question is belong to a specific category and it has a points value , for example :

```
id = 1 , student = Jack ,  question = 'What is the color of the milk' , category = Easy , points : 2.

id = 1 , student = Jack ,  question = 'What is the width of the car door' , category = medium , points : 5.

id = 2 , student = fareed ,question = ' what is the age of lionel Messi' , category = Hard , points: 3
```

and so on ,

what i want to do is to get the sum of the points belongs to the same category from the above table and store the result of the sum in another table like :

```
id= 1  , student : jack , easySumPoint = 30 , midSumPoint = 43 , HardSumPoint= 60

id=2 , student : fareed ,  easySumPoint = 21 , midSumPoint = 55 , HardSumPoint= 7
and so on
```

how i can do that ?

Comment: Group by student and category and sum the points.

Comment: you can use `->groupBy('student')` then use `->pluck('points')` sum in every group

Comment: can you please explain more in details ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
Model::groupBy('student')
    ->selectRaw('sum(points) as sum, student')
    ->lists('sum','student');
```